# Why dplyr::filter() includes data for which condition is False?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

here is something I am struggling to understand. Imagine I have a dataframe that has 2 columns:

```
**Year**      **Date**
1925          1925-01-02
1941          1925-02-03
1990          1990-01-02
1956          NA
1990          1990-01-02
2002          2004-01-02
```

And I am trying to filter out all of those entries where value in `**Year**` column does not match year in `**Date**` column.

So, I have written a small parser, for the **Date** column assuming a much larger dataset:

```
dateParser <- function(date) {
  dateStr <- toString(date)
  yearStr <- strsplit(dateStr, "-")[[1]][1]
  yearInt <- as.integer(yearStr)

  return(yearInt)
}
```

And subsequently I am using `dplyr::filter()` to filter those occurrences out:

```
noMismatch <- dplyr::filter(data, as.integer(data$Year) == dateParser(data$Date))
```

Yet still I am seeing some rows in the resulting dataframe where years do not match. Why?

P.S. Let's assume that I don't care about `NA` values in the `**Date**` column and whenever `NA` occurs I am just leaving this row in.

Comment: Does the error occur with the sample of data you present? What class is Year? I'd use `lubridate::year()`.

Comment: Look at `strsplit(dateStr, "-")[[1]][1]` -- that is only a single element, from the first row. Using that instead of a vector covering all rows, it's natural that you'd get weird results.

Comment: @Frank, I feel like you may have a point, can you please elaborate how the vectorized solution would look like? I guess I am still having troubles adjusting to a vectorized nature of R.

Comment: It depends on the tools you want to use, I think. With data.table, there's `tstrsplit`; with stringr or stringi, there's probably another way; and the best way is probably what Richard suggested -- storing as a Date object and using a `year()` extractor (found in data.table, lubridate or elsewhere). If you're sticking with base, `format` and `as.integer` can extract from a Date.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has to do with the fact that your

```
dateParser(data$Date)
```

doesn't return what you're looking for in terms of data format.

Try:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
noMismatch <- filter(data, as.integer(data$Year) == year(data$Date))
```